# Is there any way to override routes when inheriting CBV class in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a situation where I have one class that represents CRUD operations on some resource. That class has @cbv decorator attached with InferringRouter to it. However in some situations, there is need to use another class that will inherit endpoints from parent class and some of methods need to be overridden.
The problem is that when I write code in following way in SwaggerUi it displays parameters from overridden method definition, but when I make request to it it executes method from parent. How to overcome this problem?

## Code from class Student that will be parent class to StudentChild

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter
from .student import Student as ParentClass, router as parent_router
# remaining imports for pydantic models

router = InferringRouter(routes=parent_router.routes)


@cbv(router)
class StudentService(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, request: Request):
        super().__init__(request)

@router.get(
    "/list",
    summary="",
    description="",
    response_model_exclude_none=True,
    responses=errors(UnauthorizedError),
    response_class=JSONResponse,
    response_model=ListResponse[Student],
    response_model_by_alias=False
)
def get_list(self, diff_parameter:str = Query('str', description='Different parameter') -> List[Student]:
    pass #code for getting list of students, now overridden
```